# Sharing a Resourse Image in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I know there are lot of topic related to this but none of them worked for me
All i want is share a image which is stored in /drawable

here is my code

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://[my_package_name]/drawable/image1");
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
i.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"share using"));
```

its not working...

Comment: Do you get an error? Or does nothing happen when your code is called? If there is an error please provide the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: its not showing any error but when i try to share a image it crashes the third party app

Comment: Interesting, maybe the said third party app does not support opening that type of image? Maybe try creating a bitmap and sending the byte array instead, I say this because I can see the third party app trying to open the URI you passed but it does not have access to the res of your app. A third option is to grab the image in your app and save it on the SD card, then send the URI to the third party and it should be able to open it.